# Stack Exchange Data Explorer: When is the new data dump available?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

I read somewhere that more or less each month a new data dump is available. The last dump for Stack Overflow was on February 9, 2011. So when can I expect the new data dump?

Comment: Do you mean 2010 or 2011?

Comment: @Pekka Sorry 2010... Still living in the old year here.

Comment: Expect it more or less a month or more after the last update or so

Comment: @random perhaps never before has your username been more appropriate

Comment: @Daniel ahahahaha!

Comment: you may have the data confused with SEDE. Data Dump : http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/ SEDE: http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry multi collider user drop down has taken every bit of bandwidth this week

Comment: @waffles any word from the powers of when SEDE will be updated!! See comments on answer below.

Comment: See also answers to similar question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134589/on-what-day-of-the-month-is-stack-exchange-data-explorer-updated/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data dumps now only come out every two months, so you can expect a new one just after April Fool's Day. SEDE is still updated monthly, though.

> Because the dumps are quite a bit of work for us, we’re moving to a bi-monthly schedule instead of monthly. Meaning, you can expect dumps every two months instead of every month. If you have an urgent need for more timely data than this, contact us directly, or use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, which will continue to be updated monthly.

—[the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/)

EDIT:
As of September 2011, it's [every three months](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/).

Comment: but SEDE hasn't been updated since Feb 9th either =(

Comment: @giddy, hm, right you are. +1.

Comment: I've been checking it obsessively everyday since Mar 9th! =S

Comment: @giddy thanks im not the only one.

Comment: Another answer here says it's every Sunday at 3am UTC.